# What am I doing wrong in my calculations?

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have an assignment from my professor that involves the "Rule of 72". For those that don't know, the Rule of 72 is often used to determine the amount of time it will take for an amount to double, such as inflation or an investment.

Now with the Rule of 72, there is the doubling time and the actual doubling time. The doubling time according to the Rule of 72 is going to be the rate divided into 72, so it will look like 72/r. Then there is the actual doubling time. I wrote my code to count how many times the loop ran until my value doubled for the actual doubling time. It works great for the first run, but then it starts to fall apart, specifically with the actual doubling time.

- When the interest rate is 1.00%, the the doubling time is going to be
  72 and the actual doubling time is going to be 70.
- When the interest rate is 2.00%, the the doubling time is going to be
  36 and the actual doubling time is going to be 36.
- When the interest rate is 3.00%, the the doubling time is going to be
  24 and the actual doubling time is going to be 24.

  ```
  string intrate = "Interest Rate: ";
  string rule = "Rule of 72 Doubling time: ";
  string atcual = "Actual doubling time: ";
  double rate = 1;
  double rule72=72;
  double actualyears=0;
  double years=0;
  double startamnt = 1;

  for (rate=1; rate<21;rate++)
  {
      startamnt = 1;
      years = 0;
       while (startamnt < 2)
      {
          startamnt *= (1 + (rate / 100));
              actualyears+=1;
              //This part is for calculating the actual doubling time.//
      }
       years = rule72 / rate;

      lb72.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-15}{1,-15:p}", intrate, rate / 100));
      lb72.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-15}{1,-15}", rule, Math.Round(years)));
      lb72.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-15}{1,-15}", atcual, Math.Round(actualyears)));
      lb72.Items.Add(string.Format(" "));

  }
  ```

Comment: The rule is only **approximately** correct for *small* rates, because it uses the *Taylor approximation* and the natural logarithm for small numbers: *ln(1+x)* is approx *x* (a bit less), and *ln(2)/ln(1+r)* is thus approx *0.69.2/r* (a bit more). Looks thus that *69.2*-rule would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `actualyears` to zero before the `for` loop. That means that the second iteration will use the value of `actualyears` from the first iteration as start value, not zero.

Set `actualyears` to zero before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Guffa hit it right on the head. I think you accidentally meant to say "years=0" as "actualyears=0". not the other way around. Glad it worked.